# Brake pedal slow to rise when reversing

Tags: brakes, nissan, xterra

Every time we put the Xterra in reverse the brake pedal takes a long time to rise back up, releasing the brake. The pedal slowly moves up, making a noise as if the brakes are still on, then when it's all the way up it reverses just fine. Moving forward the brakes work just fine! The transmission was recently replaced (but I had the same problem before the replacement). I took it to two different mechanics and they told me to take it to the dealership. However I don't want to exorbitant prices at the dealership. Please help...

Comment: Did you consider two different mechanics saying take it to the dealership that there was good reason?

Comment: Is the car an auto?  You have pressed the brake, selected reverse, then the brake pedal slowly releases?

Comment: @HandyHowie, yes it is automatic transmission. Yes that correct pressed the brake, put on reverse then the brake pedal slowly rise. The mechanics I took the Xterra in they were not familiar with the problem

Answer (score 0):

Took to the dealership and the problem was one of the sensors!

NO CODES. DURING RESEARCH FOR ISSUE, FOUND HSA PAGE. SEEMS LIKE WHEN SYSTEM ACTIVATES ONLY IN R, THAT THE SENSORS WHERE SET ON A WRONG INCLINE. RESET SENSORS AND SYSTEM NOW FUNCTIONS CORRECTLY ON INCLINES.